# Drive Api v3: Changes watch request TeamDriveId being ignored?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to specify a Team Drive to watch according to the docs here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch

> teamDriveId | string | The Team Drive from which changes will be returned. If specified the change IDs will be reflective of the Team Drive; use the combined Team Drive ID and change ID as an identifier.

(Side note teamDriveId appears to be deprecated in favour of driveId, but the docs don't reflect that)

I read that as saying if you supply an ID only changes related to that folder (File) and its children will cause a push notification, but I still get notifications for any changes in that user's Drive.  Am I reading the docs incorrectly?

I originally [posted the question to the DotNet client library repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1378) as I'm doing this in C#.  Jon Skeet suggested that `IncludeItemsFromAllDrives` should be `false`, which seems perfectly logical and I had tried that first because of that.  However, that results in the following error being returned from the API endpoint:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "includeTeamDriveItemsRequired",
    "message": "The includeItemsFromAllDrives parameter must be set to true when driveId is specified or corpora contains drive or allDrives."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The includeItemsFromAllDrives parameter must be set to true when driveId is specified or corpora contains drive or allDrives."
 }
}
```

I've tried several variations of the following properties to see if I can restrict it down to a Team Drive, but have been unsuccessful:

- SupportsTeamDrives
- SupportsAllDrives
- IncludeItemsFromAllDrives
- RestrictToMyDrive

Clarification would be very welcome.

**Edit:**

Code as requested, it's in C#, [but the issue is likely to be the main API according to Jon Skeet](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1378#issuecomment-485753715):

```
Channel channel = new Channel()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Type = "web_hook",
    Address = [address],
    Token = [token], //max 256 chars
    Expiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(),
};

var watchRequest = _driveService.Changes.Watch(channel, startPageToken);
//watchRequest.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
watchRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;
//watchRequest.TeamDriveId = rootFolderId;
//watchRequest.IncludeTeamDriveItems = true;
watchRequest.IncludeItemsFromAllDrives = true;
watchRequest.DriveId = rootFolderId;
watchRequest.RestrictToMyDrive = true;

channel = await watchRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

I've tried several variations as the commented out code shows.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for the watch. you may also want to read https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

Comment: remember https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch is going to watch all changes on a users drive not just the teamdrive files.  Not exactly sure if this is what you are trying to achieve .

Comment: The code is c# code for the DotNet library. I'll add it, but not sure how much use it'll be.

Comment: So why is the TeamDriveId there? It states 'The Team Drive from which changes will be returned.' I'm looking for clarification on that, to me that reads as only getting changes from the Team Drive specified.

Comment: As a contributor on that project it will be an immense help in testing what you are doing 

Comment: I don't think there is a method for returning only team drive changes.  You are going to get everything if you use that method